# managedObjectContext not ready for first ViewController

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am using CoreData and although i am instantiating my managedObjectContext in AppDelegate's "willFinishLaunchingWithOptions", when my first ViewController loads it is not ready and my app crashes.

If i set a VC as root which does not use the managedObjectContext and then go to the VC that does use it, it works. I really don't know what to do since "willFinishLaunchingWithOptions" is the earliest i can get.

This is the code to init the managedObjectContext

```
-(void)useDocument
{
    NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"EtaxiDocument"];
    UIManagedDocument *document = [[UIManagedDocument alloc]initWithFileURL:url];
    self.document = document;

    if ( ! [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[url path]])
    {
        NSLog(@"doc no");
        // If the document does not exist, create it
        [document saveToURL:url
           forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating
          completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
              if (success)
              {
                  self.managedObjectContext = document.managedObjectContext;
                  NSLog(@"Document created");
              }
          }
        ];

    } else if ( document.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed ) {
        NSLog(@"doc yes");
        // If the document exists but is closed, open it
        [document openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            if (success)
            {

                self.managedObjectContext = document.managedObjectContext;
                NSLog(@"Document opened");
            } else { NSLog(@"error op doc"); }
        }];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"doc open");
        // If the document is already open, try to use it
        self.managedObjectContext = document.managedObjectContext;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you init VCs managed object context?

Comment: I have a Singleton called ApiManager which i init inside AppDelegate. That singleton calls immediately "useDocument" from above and ApiManager has a property "MOC" which i access from every VC.

That "self.managedObjectContext" from the code above refers to that property.

Comment: Note that `saveToURL` and `openWithCompletionHandler` work *asynchronously*. The completion handler method is called later when the save or open has completed.

Comment: Yeah thank you i know that but it would be really bad to init the first VC from my ApiManager. This class really should not know anything about VC's